# Android Market Universal App (Tablet + Phone)

Tags: android, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet, smartphone

I'm trying to find a way to support both phone screens (small, normal, large) and tablet screens (xlarge) with one app on the Android market.

The most common answer I have found is: enable xlarge screens in  in the androidManifest, but change minSdkTarget to 9. I'm hoping to support phones with sdkTarget 4 and above. Is it possible to do this all in one app?

To expand the question just slightly, will requesting permissions such as TELEPHONY and SMS prevent the app from being installed on a tablet without those capabilities?

Thanks very much for the help, -Rob

Comment: Permissions should not cause filtering on the market, the Uses-feature attribute will filter it out if the Required property is true, you have to explicitly set it to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have mutliple layout set ups; one for each of the target screen sizes. [Refer to the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to get more info on it.